# Reading in a std::array from an input stream

Tags: c++, istream, stdarray

I would like to accomplish the following (code won't compile as written because `>>` isn't overloaded for `std::array`):

```
constexpr array<char, 2> MAGIC_BYTES { 40, 23 };

void VerifyMagicHeader(istream& stream)
{
    //Read in the bytes that should be the magic bytes
    array<char, 2> buffer;
    stream >> buffer //This is the line that won't compile;

    if (buffer != MAGIC_BYTES)
    {/*throw exception here...*/}
}
```

I know that I can read in a `char[2]` instead of an `std::array<char, 2>` and get this to work but it wouldn't be as elegant. This seems like an operator that would be really helpful for `std::array` to have so I am wondering if there is a reason why it isn't implemented or if I will need to implement it myself.

Answer (score 4):

It isn't implemented as standard as there is no single way for the array to be read/written some examples:

1. as a binary stream of characters
2. as a comma separated list (what if one of your characters is a comma?)
3. as a space separated list (what if one of your characters is a space?)

Then when you add in that array is a templated class it gets even more complicated. How do you write an array of arrays?

None of the STL containers define stream operators for the same reasons.

Comment: I understand your point. But for `std::array<char, 2>` in particular it is supposed to be basically a convenience wrapper for a `char[2]` right? A `char[2]` is overloaded for the `>>` operator to read in a binary stream of characters so wouldn't it be natural for the `std::array<char, 2>` to have the same behavior. I would think that any other option (such as 2 and 3 that you listed) would be quite surprising functionalities given the current behavior of `char[2]` for the `>>` operator. Is there something wrong with my reasoning here?

Comment: @ChiuneSugihara The point is that if the standard defines the operator it is difficult for applications to define their own, reading an array as a string may not be what everybody wants

Answer (score 4):

This method is my favorite if you don't need performance (and for 2 bytes you don't need it) and is based on standard algorithms:

```
std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<char>{stream}, 2, begin(MAGIC_BYTES))
```

Now `MAGIC_BYTES` can be a `vector` or a `string` or some other container with random access!

Comment: Thanks for the response! Certainly something that I could consider using for an implementation. I am more curious about why the operator doesn't exist on `std::array` in the first place though. I would think it should have the `>>` operator and behave the same as it would for `char[]` but am not sure why that isn't the case. As in is it a bad idea to do it or is it just not there but could reasonably be there.

Comment: @ChiuneSugihara I cannot give you a reply to your answer but IMHO `std::array` is a lot more than a C++ array and have different semantics. If you need to override `operator >>` you have to do like for `std::vector`